# Reading a text File in Matlab with unspecified column number

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io

Assume that I have hundreds lines like following line:

Name Surname Grade1 Grade2 Grade3

It looks easy to obtain this data from the text with

```
[firstName,lastName,grade1,grade2,grade2] = textread(fileName,'%s %s %f %f %f');
```

However, if some students have second names, how can i prevent this structure ?

Comment: I'd probably read in the full raw row, split on the space, and then check the length of the resulting vector. If it's longer than 5 columns, assume that you have to merge two of them. This assumes, of course, that only one of the name fields could have second names. If not, you're a little screwed. If you *really* want to solve it, you should export it with a better delimiter

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that the second name is the only variable part of the data structure, you can read line-by-line with fgetl() and count the number of commas before deciding on the parsing method. Here is an example. You would put this whole block in a loop. Hopefully you don't have a ton of data to parse.

```
a = 'John, Smith, 95, 85, 71';
% inline = fgetl(fid);

if length(strfind(a,',')) == 4
    c = textscan(a,'%s %s %f %f %f', 'Delimiter',',');
    first_name = c{1}{1}
    last_name = c{2}{1}
    grades = cell2mat(c(3:5))

elseif length(strfind(a,',')) == 3
    c = textscan(a,'%s %f %f %f', 'Delimiter',',');
    first_name = c{1}{1}
    grades = cell2mat(c(2:4))
end
```